# How do I make a random quote generator not repeat quotes

Tags: javascript, random

I've searched the site for answers but the one's that come up aren't similar/specific to the code that I have written. I don't know how to modify the code so that the quotes don't repeat when the user presses a button to generate another quote.

```
var quotes = [
{
    quote: "\"Don't just exist, live\""
},
{
    quote: "\"Try to be a rainbow in someone's cloud\""
},
{
    quote: "\"Prove them wrong\""
},
{
    quote: "\"Find reasons to smile\""
},
{
    quote: "\"You get what you give\""
}
]

var quotebtn = document.getElementById('quote-btn');
var quote = document.querySelector('.quote');

quotebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

quote.innerHTML = quotes[random].quote;
})
```

Comment: Have you considered removing the quote just shown to the user from the list, so that it cannot be picked again? [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) could help you here.

Comment: A shuffle would be better I think.

Answer (score 1):

If the displayed is no longer important and can be deleted. You can do it easily with an array [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

example:

```
var quotes = [
    {
        quote: "\"Don't just exist, live\""
    },
    {
        quote: "\"Try to be a rainbow in someone's cloud\""
    },
    {
        quote: "\"Prove them wrong\""
    },
    {
        quote: "\"Find reasons to smile\""
    },
    {
        quote: "\"You get what you give\""
    }
    ]
    
    var quotebtn = document.getElementById('quote-btn');
    var quote = document.querySelector('.quote');
    
    quotebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
    
    quote.innerHTML = quotes[random].quote;
    quotes.splice(random, 1); // Trim one from the specified index.
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
quotebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(quotes.length) {
        
        let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
        quote.innerHTML = quotes[random].quote;
        quotes.splice(random, 1);
        
    } else {
        quote.innerHTML = "No more quotes!";
    }
})
```

`quotes.splice(random, 1)` removes quotes already presented from the array, preventing it from repeating

Once `quotes` is emptied, the `No more quotes!` message can be displayed!

Answer (score 0):

You can make another array with the same length as the quotes array and initialize it with zeros. When quote is generated set the new array at the same index as the quote to one which will mean that the quote is already generated. Next time when you generate quote check first if quote is already generated and if it is generate again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var quotes = [{
    quote: "\"Don't just exist, live\""
},{
    quote: "\"Try to be a rainbow in someone's cloud\""
},{
    quote: "\"Prove them wrong\""
},{
    quote: "\"Find reasons to smile\""
},{
    quote: "\"You get what you give\""
}];
quotes.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
var quotebtn = document.getElementById('quote-btn');
var quote = document.querySelector('.quote');
var actualQuote = 0;
quotebtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(actualQuote>=quotes.length){
        quote.innerHTML = "No more quotes";
    } else {
        quote.innerHTML = quotes[actualQuote % quotes.length].quote;
        actualQuote++;
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="quote-btn">Quote</button><br>
<span class="quote"></span>
```

I just shuffle the quotes at start. At click I display the first, and the next one, etc.
If you want it not to stop after last one just remove the condition and it will cycle trough all. So after the last it will start from the beginning.